# What are the best practices for writing a custom Keras Layer in regard to reduced duplicate code, configuration, and storage?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am a bit confused about writing a Keras Layer following the [best](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) [practices](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#custom_objects).  It feels like there is a bit of duplicate code and duplicate configuration.

Specifically, my goal is to bundle a couple of existing layers together.  The bundling will be used to ease transfer learning and visual model inspection/debugging.  An example of the code is:

```python
import tensorflow.keras as keras

class CategoricalEmbedding(keras.layers.Layer): 
  def __init__(self, vocabulary, embedding_dimensions, embedding_matrix, **kwargs):  
    self.lookup = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.IntegerLookup(
      num_oov_indices=1, mask_value=None, vocabulary=vocabulary
    )    
    self.embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(
      len(vocabulary) + 1, embedding_dimensions, input_length=1,
      weights=[embedding_matrix]
    )
    super(CategoricalEmbedding, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
  def call(self, categorical_ids):
    indexes = self.lookup(categorical_ids)
    embeddings = self.embedding(indexes)
    resized = K.squeeze(embeddings, -2)
    return resized
  
  def get_config(self):
    return {
      "vocabulary": self.lookup.get_vocabulary(),
      "embedding_dimensions": self.embedding.output_dim,
      "embedding_matrix": self.embedding.weights[0],
      **super(CategoricalEmbedding, self).get_config()
    }
```

My two issues with the above code is the requirement to write a `get_config()` and the duplicate information that is already be contained in a sub-layer's weights/config.  Specifically, all of the information needed to reconstruct the `CategoricalEmbedding` Layer exists in the sub-layers of `IntegerLookup` and `Embedding`.   Manually writing out the `get_config()` may lead to defects.  Also, the `IntegerLookup.vocabulary` will be serialized in two spots --- one in the weights/config of the `IntegerLookup` and one in the config of `CategoricalEmbedding`.  Since `vocabulary` can be millions of values, the extra configuration costs are not inconsequential.

Another way --- don't use Keras Layer, instead use Keras Model:

```python
import tensorflow.keras as keras
    
def categorical_embedding(vocabulary, embedding_dimensions, embedding_matrix, name=None):
  model_name = name if name is not None else "categorical_embedding"
  
  lookup = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.IntegerLookup(
    num_oov_indices=1, mask_value=None, vocabulary=vocabulary
  )
  lookup.weights[0].name = "lookup_weights" # fix for serialization issue
  embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(
    len(vocabulary) + 1, embedding_dimensions, input_length=1, weights=[embedding_matrix]    
  )
  squeeze = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda net: K.squeeze(net, -2), name="squeeze_to_one_embedding")
  
  return keras.Sequential([lookup, embedding, squeeze], name=model_name)
```

Is this the best way to write the above Keras Layer?  Should a Keras Layer be used for such a simple composition?  Is there a better way to write the Keras Layer to reduce code and/or serialization/storage costs?  Should Keras Models be used this way?  (Am I missing something fundamental?)

Comment: The embeddings themselves can be precomputed with any of a number of algorithms and then used in any given model by constructing the embedding layer with `weights=` and `trainable=false`

Comment: Great point - I added the even larger embedding weights to the sample code.  The initialization comes from [Using pre-trained word embeddings in a Keras model](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) guide.